# Listing blog entries by month

Tags: php, sql, blogs

I am writing custom code to create a blog. I need the archives page to list all the blog entries by month. I cannot come up with a way to do that. 
I guess it should not be too tough as it is a common feature on all blogs.
The table structure is (postid, posttitle, publishdate, .....)

Comment: Although this is fairly simple, and there will be a 'standard' SQL way to do this, it would help to know what RDBMS you are using. SQL Server? MySQL? Postgres? Oracle? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but if you want just numbers of all posts per month, use a query like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(publishdate, '%Y%m') AS publishmonth, count(*) AS entrycount
FROM entries GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(publishdate, '%Y%m')
```

If you want all posts for a particular month:

```
SELECT * FROM entries WHERE publishdate > '2009-01' AND publishdate < '2009-02';
```

And if you want to list *all* posts grouped by month on a single page, just select them sorted by `publishdate` and do the grouping locally.

Answer (score 0):

If your entries come from a SQL database, it's easiest to ask that to perform the sort for you using an `ORDER BY`. Something like

```
select * from posts order by publishdate
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this pseudo-code:

```
SELECT `publishdate` FROM `entries` ORDER BY DESC `publishdate` GROUP BY YEAR(`publishdate`), MONTH(`publishdate`);
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $date = mysql_real_escape_string($date)
    SELECT * FROM `entries` WHERE `publishdate` = $date
}
```

I think.

Comment: Firstly, this won't work since publishdate isn't the same for all the posts in a month.

Secondly, SQL queries should never happen in such a loop.